# nN visible @interface for "SecondViewController" declares the selector "category"

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I have a problem while performing a show segue between two ViewControllers. I have a button with a tag and want to receive this attribute in the second View which is opened by the button. But at the moment I only get a "No visible @interface for "SecondViewController" declares the selector "category"". I know that there are several similar on SO but I somehow can't get on the right track.

My prepareForSegue method in FirstViewController.m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"MySegue"]) {
        // Get destination view
        CardsCollectionViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        //Get button tag number (or do whatever you need to do here, based on your object
        NSInteger tagIndex = [(UIButton *)sender tag];
        NSLog(@"The category %li : ", (long)tagIndex);
        // Pass the information to your destination view
        [vc category : tagIndex];
    }
}
```

My receiving class secondViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CardCollectionViewCell.h"

@interface SecondViewController : UICollectionViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>

@property NSInteger *category;

@end
```

The imports in the first class are ok, I just left them out in the code samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a property name `category` the standard getter method will be `category` but the setter method will be entitled `setCategory:`.  So amend your code to:

```
    [vc setCategory:tagIndex];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that fixed my problem but now I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1) error in the secondViewController.h at the @property line. Could you help again, please?

Comment: Can't immediately see why, but you are casting `vc` as `CardsCollectionViewController`, but the .h is for a `SecondViewController` class.  May be linked to that.

Comment: No sorry that was just something I forgot to change for SO. Wanted to make it better understandable.

Comment: @RobinEllerkmann Just realised - you don't need the * in the property definition for NSIntegers: change it to `@property NSInteger category;`.

Comment: I have changed my property according to your comment. But I still get that error (except when tagIndex = 0). Do I have to initialize it or something?

Comment: No, NSInteger does not need initialisation.  If you step through in the debugger, which line does it give the error on?

Comment: The error occurs in '@property NSInteger category;'. I call the function you provided in your answer and this happens as the next step.

Comment: Sorry, I've tried a few things to recreate this problem, with no luck.  I can only suggest cleaning your build (Product -> Clean in the menus).  But if that doesn't solve it, others may be able to help if you repost with the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

Comment: I guess cleaning and rebuilding fixed the problem. Thanks for your afford!